# Query IP Address from unplugged NIC using C# and WMI

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm somewhat new to VS 2013, C#, and WMI, although I am familiar with C and C++ and Linux scripting. I'm trying to query the IP Address of a wired network interface in a laptop that may or may not be plugged in. This network interface, but no others, will be modified several more times by the program, so I'm trying to avoid using MO Searcher/Collection if I can, because searching seems to take a few seconds each time. So I do:

```
string WMIQuery = null;
string NICIndex = "7"; //found and set by earlier code
WMIQuery = String.Format("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration.Index='{0}'", NICIndex);

ManagementObject NICConfig = new ManagementObject(@"root\CIMV2", WMIQuery, null);

if (NICConfig["DHCPEnabled"].ToString() == "False")
{
    string[] x = (string[])NICConfig["IPAddress"];
    foreach (string y in x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(y);
    }
}
```

If the NIC is plugged in, this works, but if it's not, then it throws an exception, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

So then I tried to query if the NIC is enabled (and if not I would try to enable it):

```
WMIQuery = String.Format("Win32_NetworkAdapter.Index='{0}'", NICIndex);
ManagementObject NICAdapter = new ManagementObject(@"root\CIMV2", WMIQuery, null);

Console.WriteLine(NICAdapter["NetEnabled"].ToString()); //throws exception
```

Which gives me the error "Invalid object path", whether it's plugged in or not.

I've been beating my head on this one for a few days now, can anyone help me out?

EDIT: Found the problem with the second part, it should be `"Win32_NetworkAdapter.DeviceID='{0}'"`, it seems that the DeviceID is the same as the Index (I still need to confirm that). I still could use a hand with the first part, I tried enabling the NIC and the enable method returns 0 (success), but checking it afterward it's again/still disabled.

Comment: Maybe `"Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration.Index={0}"` query without apostrophes as `Index` property is of _Long_ type?

Comment: Index is a long, but the WMI query is a string, hence it's a string. I just tried it anyways, and even got rid of the WMIQuery part and hardcoded it to my laptop's NIC index, it didn't help with either problem.

Comment: How did you find NICIndex == 7?  Was this with it unplugged?  Because it seems this index doesn't exist, hence your code above returns a null instance. I don't know about the WMI way of accessing network adapters. I've used The native IPHelper API with much success though.

Comment: You are right, querying `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` works well for both textual and numeric comparison in a `where`  clause: `where "index='0'"` and `where "index=0"` outputs the same result...

Comment: @DavidChing: the NICIndex is found by code that first performs a WMI search for wired NICs (using manufacturer and description to cull out virtual and wireless adapters), and returns the MAC address, which will be stored in a config file (eventually if multiple NICs match the search there will be a UI to select the correct one). Another function takes the MAC address, performs another search, and returns the index. The correct MAC address and index are returned by both functions regardless of state. IPHelper looks like exactly what I needed when I started this.

Comment: I had assumed NICConfig was what was null, but perhaps it is valid and it is something referenced after that that is null. Can you debug it to see what is null?  If it is the IPAddress, that being null is actually valid because if he adapter is not connected, there can be no IP address. So you could just code that check.

Comment: I found the problem. NICConfig is still valid, as are most of its properties (including index, MAC, etc), but IP configuration info will return null values - even if it's a static IP that shows up in the windows IP configuration.

Comment: NetworkAdapter.DeviceID corresponds to NetworkAdapterConfiguration.Index, yes. Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216(v=vs.85).aspx) for info on how to match the two together, and filter out adapters which are not interfaces we normally would want/need.